# Selenium-Browser not maximized as part of CI

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Implemented CI using Selenium C#. the issue we face is the browser is not maximized when it runs as part of CI, since it runs as background process.The browser is always minimized as per failure screenshots. Since our application not designed for minimized window or mobile, few buttons are not even visible in the browser when minimized, but exist during max mode. Tried forcing chrome to start in maximized mode by using maximize method , also tried passing the chrome options, but no success. These are known issues with our app,but is there a work around to handle this in Selenium C#?

Answer (score 1):

When you new up your `WebDriver` do the following:

```
webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

That will then make the browser full screen.

Comment: It does not maximize with above command when I run the test as part of CI, since the test run in background. So you do not see any UI.

Comment: @Chan1385 when you say CI you mean on the Build server? Have you looked at an alternate solution by using Selenium GRID?

Comment: Not on Build Server,but on test VM. All Octopus does is, it drops the my latest checked in code to the test server where execution is kicked off. On test VM, when latest auto code deployed, test runs as background process instead of UI.

Comment: Ah ok, Then the only thing I can suggest is if you set up a GRID2 Server and point your tests to the Gird Server so they can run somewhere else but testing the code on the VM.

Comment: @Jamie-Thanks for your suggestions. I think using grid might be the way to go about. I did find a work around that without grid-by just capturing the window size when run as part of CI and run the same in my local machine.  That way, I can handle all the scrolling & click controls prior to deploy as part of CI.